# How much lasting harm did Ron's arm suffer from the Apparition accident (Splinching)

Tags: harry-potter

In *Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows*, when Hermione Apparates Ron from the Black manor to the forest, Ron suffers and Apparation accident (Splinching): a large chunk of meat is missing from his upper arm.  Hermione gives him magical first aid, but she can't put him completely right because she isn't experienced in healing magic.  They are unable to seek professional help about the injury, because they are a fugitives.

However, I don't remember Ron's injury mentioned again later in the book.  How much lasting injury did Ron suffer?  Did it heal completely already during the war?  Could something be done to fix it after the war, months later?

Comment: Don't want to do an answer as I think it'll be a bit short and speculative. I believe it was healed(not fully) with Essence of Dittany then it took a few days / weeks (timeline is not too clear in this part of the books) of rest and possibly reapplication of the Dittany.

Comment: This bothered me a lot when reading the book many years ago. I couldn't get over it not being mentioned again, and it ruined my reading experience of the book 7.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When Ron saved Harry (at that time Harry was finding the sword of Godric Gryffindor) in the lake, at that time he was absolutely healthy because he pulled Harry out of the lake with his arms.

Considering this I think he was *very fine* before the war.

And if he was still not alright, then Harry wouldn't tell him to destroy the locket with the sword:

> **Ron raised the sword in his shaking hands**: The point dangled over the frantically swiveling eyes, and Harry gripped the locket tightly, bracing himself, already imagining blood pouring from the empty windows.

Another line from the *Deathly Hallows*:

> Nothing but the shock of hearing that voice could have given Harry the strength to get up. Shivering violently, he staggered to his feet. There before him stood Ron, fully dressed but drenched to the skin, his hair plastered to his face, **the sword of Gryffindor in one hand and the Horcrux dangling from its broken chain in the other.**

Comment: That was an emergency, it seemed urgent to pull out Harry no matter the state of his arms.  For a similar situation, see http://www.giantitp.com/comics/oots0947.html .

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the seventh book the wound looked like flesh had been scooped out. Splinchings can usually be fixed as we must remember in the 5th or 6th book I think it was Susan Bones who removed her leg and it was later put back on. These splinchings can be fixed, but back to the Ron question, since later in the book the arm was healed, There is still probably a hole where his flesh used to be. As she was not confident enough to use advanced healing on his arm and it probably healed like a regular arm healed, leaving a hole or shallow area. Since it wasn't magically done there is still hope that it could be reversed if he goes to St. Mungos but that is unlikely since it is probably healed and the magic couldn't "sense" a wound. If that makes since. Also we must remember after he left and came back in the seventh book his arm appeared to be fine as he was quite active in the war and in the battle in Gringotts vault. Aslo in the ending there was no mention to his arm being stiff, or disfigured, his "war wound" didn't appear to be anything important.

Answer (score 0):

I believe Ron wasn't fully healed. In the forest, (Muggle-Medically) the ground was full of bacteria and other things that could infect the wound. It needed, although Hermione tried her best, care that would put him completely right, before it could get infected. But If Madam Pomfrey was there to witeness the event,Ron would be healed, with a few scars.